# Is there a way to override the paintComponent method within an MenuItemActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, overriding, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have created a demo program that paints an unusual set of objects. It does this by overriding the `paintComponent` method of a class that extends `JPanel`. This class is instanced and the objects and text are painted in the `JPanel`.

I would like to paint these objects in a `JPanel` that was previously contained in a `JFrame`, in response to a click on a menu it.

The `paintComponent` method of the  would need to be overriden in a

```
private void demoMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}
```

Is it possible to override the `paintComponent` method of a previously defined `JPanel`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change a method of an object that has already been created?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

> s it possible to override the paintComponent method of a previously defined JPanel?

Yes, you provide properties to the panel. The paintComponent() method then checks the state of these properties when doing the custom painting.

So all the actionPerformed() method does is get a reference to the panel and then set the property.

For example you could have a basic class that paints a rectangle:

```
public class RectanglePanel extends JPanel
{
    private boolean squareFilled = false;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        if (squareFilled)
        {
            g.setColor( getForeground() );
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void toggleSquareFilled()
    {
        squareFilled = !squareFilled;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

So then the ActionListener code would just be:

```
rectanglePanel.toggleSquareFilled();
```

The above code assumes that "rectanglePanel" is an instance variable pointing to your RectanglePanel.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will adapt your solution and try it.